# How to allocate unallocated free disk space in linux(fedora)

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm a newbie for linux and I'm using fedora 19. My HDD has 160GB, but in installation I used only around 60GB for /,home ...etc. Now what I want is add that free space to the system for auto mount with system bootup.

I searched on the internet but couldn't find reliable answer since I need my existing data safe..

Thank you very much for your kind help...

Comment: This question would be better placed on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), but look at using `parted`. There are graphical tools like gparted or KDE partition manager if you have a graphical window system installed

Comment: thanx arco I got it. thnx again.